# Can a form displayed as none / hidden be submitted?

Tags: php, html, forms, security

On my website I hide a form if someone doesn't have the privileges to use it.

This is simply done by changing its call using a php variables and then:

```
display: none;
```

My question is, could a user still somehow submit / edit information in this form and submit?

I do have fall backs when processing the form, but just curious.

Comment: Of course they could. Open his or her web inspector, find the form element in question, remove the css rule, done.

Comment: Very true... I shall make sure my checks when processing is secure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Once the data is in the browser, users have full control over it. At the simplest end of the spectrum, they can use the developer tools in their browser to make the form visible.

Not including the form in the page isn't sufficient protection though. The user can always create their own form from scratch or manually write an HTTP request.

You need to perform authentication and authorization when the request to the form's action URI is received.

Comment: And could it be submited just using `submit()` method?

Comment: Yes. The use has full control over it. They can call its submit method, they can add a new submit button to it, etc.

Comment: I was curious whether form being hidden does not behave like a disabled input field. When I was making fake ajax forms for compatibility, I used to avoid `display:none` for them.

Comment: The `display` of a form has no impact on the submitability of the fields in it.